# I would like to know if a Research paper is possible for making a change in Open Source software tool

Tags: publications, research-topic

I have been using this open-source network flow generator and after doing some research i was able to add a network classification engine based on ML into it, put it in other words i added a new feature into it.

So i would like to know if a research paper is possible for such work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in general, the answer would be no. However, if you can, somehow, show the usefulness of the tool by applying it to some difficult problem, then that falls more into the realm of research and so warrants publication. But it isn't the tool, per se, that classifies it as research.

Note that in CS, many doctoral dissertations start out with the student building something. This can take a lot of time and effort. But then, they show that the tool is better in some way that the state of the art. It is that demonstration that gives it value and leads to the degree. Advances in operating systems and databases are often like this.

Build a tool. Show that it extends the state of the art (faster, smaller, more secure,...). Now publish.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible to know without further details. It might be, it might not. You might want to have a look at the Machine Learning Open Source Software track of the Journal of Machine Learning Research, accessible here: http://www.jmlr.org/mloss/

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the primary determinate of whether this could be a viable research paper is what level of work that you are willing to commit to transform your current accomplishment into appropriately formatted research (for a particular journal, and for review by whichever professor is supervising your work). To accomplish this transformation, you must answer the question of how your work accomplishes a certain objective differently than others, and how it might be better. If you can answer this question successfully, and convincingly, you could make this paper work. Make sure that you talk to your supervising professor so that he or she could make suggestions as to where you go next with this, however. Research requires guidance, initially, and is rarely done completely unaided.